# jquery cant transform json response

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, encoding

I'm using jquery with the form plugin to handle the submit, but when the client receive the server response it cant pass it to a json object:

```
var options = { 
    success: showResponse,   
    dataType: 'json',
    error: errorhandler
};
$('#UserEditForm').ajaxForm(options);
```

The server response is generate with the _json_encode_ php function.
When I submit the form, always the *errorhandler* function is called and I check the response with firebug it comes with some kind of a space after the first "{"

```
" {"status":1"}"
```

, that with *utf-8* encode and something like:

```
"ï»¿ï»¿ï»¿{"status":1}"
```

with *iso-8859-1*.

Thanks!!

Comment: What does the JSON response from the server actually look like? E.g., in Firebug or Chrome's dev tools or...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you send headers with your server reply?

Otherwise, try:

> header('Content-type: application/json');

Also, I've had problems with jQuery not reading some large chunks of data in JSON correctly, and I used the parse method from json.org:
https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js

Comment: I try adding the header, but with this the behavior is worst!!